# How to parse json that has multiple type(datatype) of values for single key

Tags: swift, parsing, alamofire

I am using **Alamofire** with **SwiftyJson** for api calls.On one of the api  Call, I need to parse a response that has array of objects.
For Example sample json:

```
 totalValues =(
            {                   
                title = "Sub-Total";
                value = 564;
            },
            {                 
                title = "Convenience";
                value = 40;
            },
            {                  
                title = "Transaction Total";
                value = 604;
            },
            {                   
                title = "Old Wallet";
                value = "-41.6667";
            },
            {    
                title = "TOTAL";
                value = 562;
            },
            {    
                title = "New Wallet Balance";
                value = 0;
            }
        );
```

Now I struck at how to create model class for this?Which data type I need to give for the `value`.If I add `Any` to the key..I am getting `Type 'Total'(class name) does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'`

Or is there any other way to parse this??

Can someone give me solution for this??

Thanks in advance

I am parsing the response json like below:

```
if response.result.value != nil {
                    do{
                        let jsonObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self,from: response.data!)
                        single(.success(jsonObject))
                    }catch let error {

                         single(.failure(error))

                    }
                }else if let error = response.result.error as NSError? {
                    single(.failure(error))
                }else if let error = response.result.error {
                    single(.failure(error))
                }
```

Comment: Get a stick, find the developer how thought this format was a "good idea" and ... well, look all passive aggressively at them . You will need to manually decode those properties by overriding the `int(from: Decoder)`

Comment: First of all forget `SwiftyJSON`. It's a honorable library but became obsolete in favor of `Codable`. An answer depends on whether you want the `String` type or  whether the string can be converted to `Double`. And please add the code you are using.

Comment: @vadian I want the Double value..also added the code I am using to parse it.

Comment: You are not printing the JSON. You are printing a NSDictionary. Please edit your question and post your actual json. `print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "nil")`

Comment: [Support multiple types in codable — swift](https://medium.com/@sajjadsarkoobi/support-multiple-types-in-codable-swift-de461689e21b) might help